# Is there a way to use Entity Context in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC, but the tutorial I am using is ASP.NET MVC 3 (this is the best, specific tutorial I have come across). I have hit a road block when I am asked to connect the SQL Server to my project using a code-first approach.

I have altered the `web.config` file and created a new class to represent the Entity Framework. After I attempted this, I just got errors (particularly the `using System.Data.Entity;` is not recognized, and neither is `DbContext` nor  `DbSet`).

I believe what the tutorial recommended was outdated, and I tried researching for an up to date solution, but couldn't find anything. It could also be that the `<connectionStrings>` section that I added to my config file is at fault, but I couldn't find anything on that either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MVCMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For reference, the tutorial page:

[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4#adding-the-app_data-folder)

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core MVC, why not follow [its specific tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Comment: @Herohtar > If you're new to ASP.NET Core web development, consider the Razor Pages version of this tutorial, which provides an easier starting point. :)

Comment: I was using the tutorial because it shows how to add a shopping cart to the app as well as a code first approach.

Answer (score -1):

The tutorial you're following is stamped 04/21/2011, I recommend something fresher.

You could follow [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core - Tutorial 1 of 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) which has been update to work with 3.0.

> The Visual Studio instructions use SQL Server LocalDB, a version of SQL Server Express that runs only on Windows.
>
> The Visual Studio Code instructions use SQLite, a cross-platform database engine.

Antother option is [Get Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project).

(One uses EF Core, the other use EF not Core).

Comment: Thanks for the more recent tutorial, I'll go through that next. I am currently using this tutorial because the app it creates is perfect for what I want to learn. Is there a way to continue with it?

Comment: Yes and no. Is it possible? Yes. Should you do it? Most likely no..2011 is really far behind in the .NET world. c#, MVC, EF, .NET Core changed significantly since 2011. I'd recommend following a more recent tutorial. Being a beginner and trying to fit a 2011 .NET tutorial into .NET core is very ambitious. I'm no guru, but I'm not a beginner either, and  I wouldn't do it.